# normal method not working but volley method works perfectly

Tags: android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview

am using a normal method and volley on_response or on_error method. my code is to fetch data from sqlite and add it to  an array list and create an adapter with this list and setting this adapter to an autocompletetextview.  i use same line of codes for this purpose in both methods but in normal method only one element will be there in adapter but in volley method there will be all elemts in the adapter, i can't understand what's the problem. i need to normal method get worked

noramal methos :

```
 private void prepareMyLists() {
        ArrayList<String> arrlist = new ArrayList<String>();
                String selectQuerys = "select distinct location from tb_user where location like" +
                        "'"+autoservice.getText().toString()+"%'"+" or "+"'% "+autoservice.getText().toString()+"%'";
                SQLiteDatabase dbs = sq.getReadableDatabase();
                Cursor cursors = dbs.rawQuery(selectQuerys, null);
                while (cursors.moveToNext())
                    arrlist.add((cursors.getString(cursors.getColumnIndex("location"))));

                    adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            getBaseContext(),
                            R.layout.drop_list_item,
                            arrlist);

                    autocompletetextview.setAdapter(adapter1);
            }
    }
```

Volley Method :

```
 private void prepareMyList() {
        String LOCATION = "http://android.thusharaphotos.com/sear778ch11.php";


        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,LOCATION, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {


            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                ArrayList<String> arrlist = new ArrayList<String>();
                String selectQuerys = "select distinct location from tb_user where location like" +
                        "'"+autoservice.getText().toString()+"%'"+" or "+"'% "+autoservice.getText().toString()+"%'";
                SQLiteDatabase dbs = sq.getReadableDatabase();
                Cursor cursors = dbs.rawQuery(selectQuerys, null);
                while (cursors.moveToNext())
                    arrlist.add((cursors.getString(cursors.getColumnIndex("location"))));

                    adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            getBaseContext(),
                            R.layout.drop_list_item,
                            arrlist);

                    autocompletetextview.setAdapter(adapter1);
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("location_name", autoservice.getText().toString());
                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getBaseContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

onclick for autocompleteTextView

```
autocompletetextview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                setLocation((String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position));

            }
        });
```

Comment: Where is sq defined?

Comment: Sq defined in oncreate

Comment: While debugging are both the arrlist's the same size?

Comment: array list and adapter is same size

Comment: but onitemClickListner of autocompletetextview the parent gets only one item means parent.getCount()=1 always

Comment: I mean the list running in either method.

Comment: but when we use volley method  parent.getCount()= arraysize, it works fine

Comment: list running in two method has same size but at onclick they receives only one item in normal method but when we use volley onclick get all items in array

Comment: Add `onClick()` code.

Comment: `autocompletetextview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                setLocation((String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position));

            }
        });  `

Answer (score 0):

Move your `new ArrayAdapter` and `setAdapter` outside the while loop.

If both your examples are in app char for char, this is already done in the volley example.